# Javascript Regular Expression Difference

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following html code:

```
<input id="buttonClickOne" type="button" value="Click 1" @click="buttonOneClicked">
```

In my script I have a regular expression to pull the @click name and its value:

```
let arrEvents = source.match(/ @click="([^"]*)"/g);
```

I get the output that I'm expecting:

```
[" @click="buttonOneClicked""]
```

So I modified the reg exp so that I can have different events I may want to search for:

```
const arrEventTypes = ['@click'];
for(let event_type of arrEventTypes){
    let reg = new RegExp(' ' + event_type + '="([^"]*)"', 'g');
    let arrEvents = reg.exec(source);
    ...
}
```

But my output is different:

```
[" @click="buttonOneClicked"", "buttonOneClicked"]
```

If I look at the RegExp that I create it looks correct:

```
" @click="([^"]*)""
```

Am I missing something?

**Solution**

Thanks for the link. It makes more sense now. I started the expression version while I was coding but Touffy made a good point about using the DOMParser which actually worked better for my needs.

Comment: [You can't parse HTML with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use a DOMParser instead then you can use `getAttribute("@click")`.

Comment: you're using `match` in the first one and `exec` in the second

Comment: @Touffy For some tasks, it is OK. The question you linked to was asking for a generic way to handle all HTML cases (that would not work). The OP just wants this specific syntax.

Comment: @JuanMendes I assume the OP simplified his example to better illustrate the specific problem with `exec`. He probably wants to parse a whole component's HTML for those Vue-like event attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm repeating myself about this issue, but let's have a go at it one more time.

First, the browser is very good at parsing HTML. Parsing HTML is its primary feature. So, let the browser do its job:

```
source = `<input id="buttonClickOne" type="button" value="Click 1" @click="buttonOneClicked">`
dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(source, 'text/html')
```

Now you have a fully parsed object which supports all the nice DOM features you're used to (I hope) such as:

```
dom.body.firstElementChild.getAttribute('@click')
// returns "buttonOneClicked"
```

I know, it may look like a slight overkill in your example, but it's not that expensive and I assume your example is simplified anyway.

Comment: What if this is being run server side, or in a web worker? The question is really about getting multiple matches from a regex.

Comment: Yes, I know I'm solving the problem without answering the question. I couldn't fit all that in a comment though. Web Workers and node.js do make regexes more attractive but [there are DOM libraries](https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/846) to replace DOMParser there.